# Issue Streaming Video with WebTorrent

Tags: javascript, node.js, webtorrent

I am working on streaming videos with WebTorrent and For some links videos are not rendering,
**like** *magnet:?xt=urn:btih:08ada5a7a6183aae1e09d831df6748d566095a10&dn=Sintel&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexplodie.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.empire-js.us%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.btorrent.xyz&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.fastcast.nz&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openwebtorrent.com&ws=https%3A%2F%2Fwebtorrent.io%2Ftorrents%2F&xs=https%3A%2F%2Fwebtorrent.io%2Ftorrents%2Fsintel.torrent* **this link is working fine but could not load this link** https://yts.mx/torrent/download/6C74A650AFC100BBF256AC978A49498E080B3F28.

```
const client = WebTorrent();
const magnetURL = 'https://yts.mx/torrent/download/6C74A650AFC100BBF256AC978A49498E080B3F28'

client.add(magnetURL, function (torrent) {
  torrent.files.forEach(function (file) {
    let video = torrent.files.find(function (file) {
      return file.name.endsWith('.mp4');
    });
      const xpi = document.getElementById('video-container');
      video.renderTo(xpi, function (err, element) {
        // console.log(magnetURL);
      });
    console.log(video.name);
  });
});
```

Comment: Without logs or anything it's very difficult to understand what is not working here. Could you provide us with more information regarding these two torrents? From what i see the torrent linked is not working anymore.